# fetch().then().catch(); doesn't catch `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The user aborted a request.`

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise, try-catch

I have an interface on an ESP32.
I am trying to have a `Connected` variable show up in an interface to signal the user if he is connected to said interface or not.

I am using the following method to constantly GET the configuration from the server in order update the interface.

```js
// get json
async function get_json(api_path, options = {}) {
    // const url = api_path;
    // console.log(ROOT_URL);
    // console.log(api_path);
    const { timeout = 8000 } = options;
    const controller = new AbortController();
    const timeoutID = setTimeout(() => controller.abort(), timeout);

    const response = await fetch(api_path, {
        ...options,
        signal: controller.signal,
    });
    clearTimeout(timeoutID);
    return response.json();
}

async function getSettings() {
    get_json("/api/settings/get", {
        timeout: 5000,
    }).then((json_data) => {
        // do something with the data
        connected = true;
    }).catch(function (error) {
        // request timeout
        console.log(error);
        connected = false;
        console.log(error.name === "AbortError");
    });
}
```

Everything works dandy except the `catch` part.

Let's say the user changes the IP of the ESP. The ESP restarts and reconfigures to use the newly IP address. But the user stayed on the same page because `connected` is still set to `true`. In the console I get `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The user aborted a request.` for each request to `getSettings()` because I can't write a proper `catch`.

Basically, after the IP is changed, `getSettings()` tries to GET from a wrong address, so it's normal to throw some sort of error which I should **catch** and change the `Connected` variable to false and update it in the interface so that the user can go/move/navigate to the IP Address they have just inputted.

#### Edit:

This is how I update connected in the interface:

```
// check if connected to ESP
function connectedStatus() {
    let conn = document.getElementById("connected");
    conn.innerHTML = connected ? "Yes" : "No";
}

setInterval(connectedStatus, 500);
```

Comment: Your getSettings is not returning the promise from get_json, try `return get_json(...`. You can also get rid of the `async` if your not using `await`

Comment: Your code works fine for me, calling `getSettings()` does log "*DOMException: The user aborted a request.*" as the value for `error` and "*true*" for the comparison of the error name; there is no uncaught rejection.

Comment: You say "*But the user stayed on the same page because `connected` is still set to `true`*", but you have not shown the part of your code where you use `connected` and redirect the user.

Comment: `return response.json();` should be `return await response.json();`

Comment: @Bergi I can't redirect the user, because I change the network settings of the ESP by restarting it. If I restart it, then the server is down so I won't have a path to redirect to. `connected` is in the code above. I have updated the question with the `connected` function.

Comment: @Barmar. Why's that?,.   If you return a promise inside an async function, I was off the understanding it just gets forwarded anyway.  IOW it doesn't end up resolving with a Promise..  Or could you explain why it matters..

Comment: @Keith I could be wrong, I don't do any promise programming.

Comment: @Keith Could you expand on that ? Inside `async function get_json(){}` I have `const response = await fetch();` and then `return response.json()`. Adding `return` to `get_json` did not change anything.

Comment: Without the return in `getSettings` you have just created a function that will always resolve with undefined, even if `get_json` fails. It might not be what's causing your issue.

Comment: As @keith suggest You should return a promise from `getSettings` or use `await` keyword before  `get_json`

Comment: @Keith Can you create an answer based on this, explaining more ? Because I don't understand why my code doesn't work even though I have `const response = await fetch()` inside `async function get_json()` which I call in `function getSettings() { get_json().then().catch() }`. Doesn't `get_json()` return a promise because `const response = await fetch()` ? So why wouldn't `get_json().then()` work inside `getSettings()` ?

Comment: @Nur Can you expand on that ? `async function get_json()` returns `response`, which is `const response = await fetch()`. Doesn't `get_json()` return a PROMISE ? So why doesn't `get_json().then().catch()` work ?

Comment: @Nur Using `await get_json()` inside `getSettings()` returns `Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules`. But `return get_json()` seems to get the job done.

Comment: In order to use `await` keyword, you need async function, Or you could return just promise,

Answer (score 1):

*"Doesn't `get_json()` return a PROMISE?"* - All async function does return promise, But your `getSettings` function doesn't wait for `get_json` to become resolved.

```js
let delay = ms => new Promise(ok => setTimeout(ok, ms));

async function asyncFn() {
    delay(2000).then(() => {
        console.log("wait! 2 secs...")
    });
    console.log("thanks for waiting")
}
asyncFn()
```

As you can see `"thanks for waiting"` print first,

So our guess is that, `getSettings` indeed modify `connected` state but not immediately but later, But your `getSettings` resolve immediately, and you didn't wait for state (`connected`) change.

So you need to wait for any changes,

```js
let delay = ms => new Promise(ok => setTimeout(ok, ms));

let state;
async function asyncFn() {
  await delay(2000).then(() => {
    state = true
    console.log("wait! 2 secs...")
  });
  console.log("thanks for waiting")
}

asyncFn().then(() => {
  console.log("state:", state)
})
```